# How to rotate a feature in OpenLayers3

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I cannot find an API to rotate a feature/geometry in OpenLayers3. How do I rotate a polygon in OpenaLayers3?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not supported at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can now rotate a polygon with OpenLayers. Rotation unit is in radians and you also need to set a point to made rotation as seen in [the API](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Geometry-Geometry.html#rotate) (link to parent class `ol/geom/geometry` that `ol​/geom/Polygon` inherits from)

You can see [a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-forked-uiiqy?file=/main.js) I made.  Below, in my sample (only JS mentioned), I use the center of the bounding box of the polygon.

To really center from centroid of the polygon, you would need to introduce JSTS, Turf (cf https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/3731#issuecomment-106718083) or use [`getInteriorPoint`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon-Polygon.html#getInteriorPoint) (for polygon) or [`getInteriorPoints`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_MultiPolygon-MultiPolygon.html#getInteriorPoints) (for multipolygon)

```js
import "ol/ol.css";
import GeoJSON from "ol/format/GeoJSON";
import Map from "ol/Map";
import VectorLayer from "ol/layer/Vector";
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import View from "ol/View";
import { Fill, Stroke, Style } from "ol/style";
import { getCenter } from "ol/extent";
import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";

var style = new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: "#319FD3",
    width: 1
  })
});

var vectorSource = new VectorSource();

var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
  style: style
});

new Map({
  layers: [vectorLayer],
  target: "map",
  view: new View({
    center: fromLonLat([1, 45]),
    zoom: 2
  })
});

fetch("data/geojson/countries.geojson")
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then((json) => {
    var features = new GeoJSON({ featureProjection: "EPSG:3857" }).readFeatures(
      json
    );
    vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
    var feature1 = vectorLayer
      .getSource()
      .getFeatures()
      .find((el) => el.get("name") === "France");
    var geom1 = feature1.getGeometry();
    var xy = getCenter(geom1.getExtent());
    geom1.rotate(-90 * (Math.PI / 180), xy);
});
```